# Loading JSON array from API into another array in Javascript using a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm pretty new to programming in general but have the problem that my array keeps being overwritten in my for loop so when I print in to the console only the last set of data is showing. i.e the data in the array is overwritten each time.

I want to store all the details in an array so I can work with the data. I have tried to put an array into an array but keep getting errors.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){
    var dailyfxTech = [];
    dailyfxTech.push((collection[i].ccyPair), (collection[i].resistance), (collection[i].support), (collection[i].trend.src));  
             }

        console.log(dailyfxTech)
```

How can I append the data to the dailyfxTech array each time it loops so that it looks like ;

```
dailyFxTech {[ccypair], [resistance], [support], [trend.src]},
            {[ccypair], [resistance], [support], [trend.src]},
            {[ccypair], [resistance], [support], [trend.src]},
            {[ccypair], [resistance], ...etc},
```

I later want to be able to reference the array to place the data in other parts of my site eg:

```
dailyFxTech[2,3] = the support of third ccy pair.
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you are redeclaring the array everytime inside the loop. just cut `var dailyfxTech = [];` and paste it before the for loop. Besides, you probably want an array of objects instead, according to your desired output.

Comment: Thanks guys, I does look like I need an array of Objects as this code lists it in one big array.. I will do a search to find this... thx

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that each time the loop is running you are declariing a new array. Super simple fix. Just need to put the `var dailyfxTech` outside of your loop.

```
  var dailyfxTech = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){
    dailyfxTech.push((collection[i].ccyPair), (collection[i].resistance), (collection[i].support), (collection[i].trend.src));  
   }

   console.log(dailyfxTech)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare var dailyFxTech outside of the for loop.

```
var dailyfxTech = [];
for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++){
    dailyfxTech.push((collection[i].ccyPair), (collection[i].resistance), (collection[i].support), (collection[i].trend.src));  
}
```

When you have the var declaration in the body of the for loop, the variable is re-allocated and the old value is trashed.